# Coldfusion CFHTTP PATCH Method

Tags: coldfusion, patch, content-type, cfhttp

I am doing a basic PATCH method call to an API using cfhttp and Coldfusion 2021.  No matter what I try to do, it changes the content-type on the call to x-www-form-urlencoded when it is set to application/json using cfhttpparam.  I tried
adding this line from another post, no effect.

```
<cfhttpparam type="CGI" encoded="false" name="Content_Type" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"<
```

I tried changing the method to POST and using this line from another post.

```
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" value="PATCH">
```

No matter what it still sends as the wrong content-type and the api disregards it as a result and just sends back a 200 OK that it received a call, but does no update to the data due to the content-type.

I have also tried sending the body as a variable and as a param. Same result.

Does anyone know why it is switching the content-types or how to correct it?

Here is my code for the call to the API.

```
<cfhttp url="#loc.URLInsertID#"
        method="PATCH"
        timeout="999"
        result="loc.AssetPandaGetObjectDataUpdate">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-Type" value="application/json" />
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Mimetype" value="application/json" />
        <!--- <cfhttpparam type="CGI" encoded="false" name="Content_Type" value="application/json; charset=utf-8"> --->
        <!--- <cfhttpparam type="header" name="X-HTTP-Method-Override" value="PATCH"> --->
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="#Bearer#">
        <!--- <cfhttpparam type="body" name="body" value="#SerializeJSON(loc.bodyElements)#"> --->
        #SerializeJSON(loc.bodyElements)#
</cfhttp>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really a comment, but it is too long.

On this section of code

```
    <!--- <cfhttpparam type="body" name="body" value="#SerializeJSON(loc.bodyElements)#"> --->
    #SerializeJSON(loc.bodyElements)#
```

You most likely want to use the `body` approach. Try to get this to work on Postman first. Usually it is straight forward to replicate the request from there.

Comment: That's the weird part, I was successful in Postman in executing the call and getting the appropriate response from their api.  But when I use that exact same format in CF, it does not work.  It will return a 200 OK from their API, but it changes the content-type as I mentioned, and is therefore ignored by their API.

Comment: I'm curious how you're determining the content-type is the problem, because posting a variation of the code (with type=body) to another .cfm script and dumping the headers shows the expected content-type for me, application-json.

Comment: Seems like the issue is on your end. Works fine from trycf.com as well.  Test: https://trycf.com/gist/a18299d9bf722505be3709b734902859/acf2021?theme=monokai Result: https://webhook.site/#!/88bf3bc8-dc22-4146-8471-ccd0ea209d32/1ca1ac1e-2ff4-4b03-875d-264bbfae69f8/1